# BaseX Updating issue or is it bad setup?

Tags: tomcat, basex

I've checked through docs and through SO for info regarding `SET WRITEBACK TRUE` in BaseX due to the nature in which it writes data updates (per documentation).

Here's the issue I'm having: On one computer (Ubuntu 15.10) I installed BaseX and, using the GUI Standalone, I can do proper updates to xml files stored in a database with a command such as:

```
let $doc := doc("item1/item1.xml")
return 
  db:replace("item1", "item1.xml", '<item itemid="86712345"><data>more meta</data></item>')
```

The expected occurs, whatever contents were in "item1.xml" get overwritten with the 3rd parameter.

UPDATE: in tomcat manager, I undeployed `Basex823.war`, downloaded and deployed `Basex831.war`, then configured "web.xml" to add the non-commented "context-param" group below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.basex.writeback</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Update queries (`replace` specifically) seems to work now, where it didn't before. Thanks for reading. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the older BaseX war file (under Windows 7) was the issue.

I did the following to resolve this:

- Downloaded war file (version 831)
- Un-deployed the 823 war file in Tomcat manager web page
- Deployed the 831 war file
- Added the context-param tag
  for org.basex.writeback and set it to true
- Restarted Tomcat server in XAMPP control panel